# Running multiple RegEx through log files

Tags: c#, regex

I need to build a program that can read through live logging, identify lines, and parse data out of the lines.

Problems I'm facing:

- The log output changes from version to version, of the logger.
- There are about 500 different types of lines that the logger can output.

There is no easy way to make this, as far as I can tell.  I was wondering if there was a specific way of doing stuff like this, as it seems pretty overwhelming?

My current solution is to read the logs and run all my Regexes through each line of the logs to test if it matches.

I have an array with a type I call `DataReader`, and each contains multiple RegEx formats to read different versions of the logger's lines.

First it tests if the `DataReader` can read it, using:

```
bool canUse(String text);
```

If it returns false, it tries another `DataReader` until it returns true.

If canUse returns true, it will then construct the data structure using

```
CompiledLogData constructData(String text);
```

I am not asking for someone to code this; I'm just asking if this is the right way, or if there is a better way, perhaps a more optimal way for this type of a thing? I am sure someone has worked with a situation like this before? :)

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the source of component that produces the logs? What would be the difference between `canUse` and `constructData` - can you give a rough example of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily a solution, but what i prefer to do in situations like these, is use the RegEx statements on the whole thing... that way you can programmatically build your lines based on reading the entire log into memory. As far as performance is concerned though, it would be the same as yours, just reverse direction (you're doing @for each Line, Do each regexp@, i do @for entire log, Do each regexp@).

What i like about the way i do it is that i can reduce the size of the log on each match by placing the match in a separate var and replacing it in the log with nothing, then move onto next regexp. Different way about it i guess...

Comment: well, if i only could do that, it sounds like a pretty good way, problem is, the feed from the Logger, is a Live UDP Connection, my client recieves 1 package(containing 1 line of log) at a time, and i do regex check on each package recieved

Comment: then you don't really have a choice do you ;) the way you're doing it, given your situation, is the best way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are bound to C# this might be a good approach. At least I do not know any better.

If you just need to transform the data into a different output format (e.g. into a file), you might use an awk script (awk was made for tasks like this). This skript might read your log messages from stdin and writes the transformed data to stdout. So you can pipe your log messages to your awk script and get the transformed data back from stdout for further processing.

Reading the log and tranforming the data are seperate applications and you have more flexibility in the usage of the tools.

Especially when the regular expressions change oftenly, you might speed up your work by using a script language to avoid the additional compile-step you need in c#.

Comment: the primary function for the program, is to pharse log data, into SQL tables, for a statistically overview, just to make that clear :)
The reason to make it 1 large program, is for the purpose of making it a Windows Service, fully standalone.
But thanks for the input.